# superclass function being called when subclass function is invoked

Tags: javascript, html, inheritance, canvas

I was really struggling coming up with a title but basically I'm working on a game in the html5 canvas and have a class called player with a subclass aiPlayer for when playing against ai. The code for updating the players looks like this:

```
  var entitiesCount = this.entities.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < entitiesCount; i++) {
      var entity = this.entities[i];
      entity.update();
      if (entity instanceof special && entity.x > WIDTH || entity.x + 200 < 0) {
          this.entities.splice(i, 1);
          entitiesCount--;
      }
  }
```

However, the aiPlayer never updates with the aiPlayer update function. I've printed out the constructor of each entity and there is one Player and one aiPlayer. However, when printing out the method they are calling, both of them are calling the Player update. Does anyone know why it would do this?
Also, if it helps, the aiPlayer update looks like:

```
aiPlayer.prototype.update = function() {
    if((this.game.timer.gameTime % this.moveTime) > (this.moveTime * 0.9)) {        
        this.chooseMove();
    }
    Player.prototype.update.call(this);
};
```

And ai constructor looks like:

```
function aiPlayer (game, character, x, y, health) {
    Player.call(this, game, character, x, y, health, PLAYER2_CONTROLS, "left");
    aiPlayer.prototype = new Player(this.game, this.character, this.x, this.y,
                                this.health, this.control, this.facing);
    aiPlayer.prototype.constructor = aiPlayer;
    this.controls = PLAYER2_CONTROLS;
    this.attackLength = 50;
    this.fleeLength = 70;
    this.moveTime = 1;
    this.prevControl = "idle";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function aiPlayer (game, character, x, y, health) {
    Player.call(this, game, character, x, y, health, PLAYER2_CONTROLS, "left");
    aiPlayer.prototype = new Player(this.game, this.character, this.x, this.y,this.health, this.control, this.facing);
    aiPlayer.prototype.constructor = aiPlayer;
    this.controls = PLAYER2_CONTROLS;
    this.attackLength = 50;
    this.fleeLength = 70;
    this.moveTime = 1;
    this.prevControl = "idle";
}
```

These lines here

```
aiPlayer.prototype = new Player(this.game, this.character, 
                                this.x, this.y,this.health, 
                                this.control, this.facing);
aiPlayer.prototype.constructor = aiPlayer;
```

are wrong. They are wrong because

- you are setting the prototype to an Instance of `Player`
- you are resetting the prototype and the constructor of the prototype of `aiPlayer` every time you create a new instance of `aiPlayer`. You should move all modifications to the prototype outside of the constructor function, like this:

-

```
function aiPlayer (game, character, x, y, health) {
    Player.call(this, game, character, x, y, health, PLAYER2_CONTROLS, "left");
    this.controls = PLAYER2_CONTROLS;
    this.attackLength = 50;
    this.fleeLength = 70;
    this.moveTime = 1;
    this.prevControl = "idle";
}

aiPlayer.prototype.someMethod = function someMethod() { 
    ....
}
```

A correct way to set the prototype of the subclass is like this

```
aiPlayer.prototype = Object.create(Player.prototype, {
    constructor : {
        value : aiPlayer
    }
};
```

This will set as the `aiPlayer` prototype a new object that inherits from `Player.prototype` (i.e. has `Player.prototype` as its prototype) and has `aiPlayer` registered as its constructor function

Also, the `.update` of `Player` is called from `aiPlayer` because you explicitly calling it here

```
aiPlayer.prototype.update = function() {
    if((this.game.timer.gameTime % this.moveTime) > (this.moveTime * 0.9)) {        
        this.chooseMove();
    }
    Player.prototype.update.call(this); //you call the Player.update()
};
```

Considering the above, this is how you should register the `aiPlayer.update`

```
aiPlayer.prototype = Object.create(Player.prototype, {
    constructor : {
        value : aiPlayer
    }
};

aiPlayer.prototype.update = function update() {
//your code here
}
```

Now, when you create a new `aiPlayer` object instance, the inheritance chain will go like this

```
aiPlayerInstance --> aiPlayer.prototype --> Player.prototype
```

and when you call `aiPlayerInstance.update()` it will first look to `aiPlayer.prototype` and since `aiPlayer.prototype` does have a method called `update` it will execute it, and it will not look any further down the inheritance chain (i.e. in `Player.prototype`)